# Save Kinect RGB to JPG file on the disk

Tags: c#, wpf, image, save, kinect

I am trying to save the Kinect RGB feed, which is displayed on an image into a jpg file using the following code

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.Create(@"d:\1.jpg"))
    {
         JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
         encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(MainViewer.Source as BitmapSource));
         encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred
>   in PresentationCore.dll

Please help.

Comment: When you run the Debug version of your application in Visual Studio, it will break execution at the line where the exception occurs. My bet would be that `MainViewer.Source as BitmapSource` is `null`.

Comment: You are correct. It shows that it is null, but it is not. It shows the video feed of the Kinect colour capture.

Comment: What type is `MainViewer.Source`?

Comment: It is a Image component for WPF which the Kinect writablebitmap is assigned to. I.e:

MainViewer.Source=KinectRGB;